# Google Map API loading dynamic info windows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, symfony, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have google maps loading locations from my database dynamically on the map. The problem is its not displaying each locations correct display information. Its only showing information from the last product on all the markers. I need to iterate through each marker somehow. My code is below:

```
<section class="content jumbotron jumbotron-full-height">
    <div class="item slide-1">
        <div id="home-map"></div>
    </div>
</section>

<script>
    var map;
    function initMap() {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('home-map'), {
            center: {lat: 52.1326, lng: 5.2913},
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            styles: [
                {
                    featureType: 'all',
                    stylers: [
                        { saturation: 0 }
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: 'road.arterial',
                    elementType: 'geometry',
                    stylers: [
                        { hue: '#00ffee' },
                        { saturation: 0 }
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: 'poi.business',
                    elementType: 'labels',
                    stylers: [
                        { visibility: 'off' }
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: 'road',
                    elementType: 'labels',
                    stylers: [
                        { visibility: 'on' }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        {% for product in products %}
            var contentString = '<div class="info-window">'+
                                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div id="window-content">'+
                                        '{% set path = product.image is not null ? product.image.path|imagine_filter(filter|default('sylius_shop_map_thumbnail')) : 'http://placehold.it/200x200' %}'+
                                        '<img src="{{ path }}" />'+
                                        '<h1>{{ product.code }}</h1>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<h2>{{ product.city }} - {{ product.country }}</h2>'+
                                    '<p><strong> Description: </strong>{{  product.shortDescription }}</p>'+
                                    '<p><strong> Price: </strong>from {{ product.price|sylius_price }} a day.</p>'+
                                    '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ path("sylius_shop_product_show", {"slug": product.slug}) }}">more info</a>'+
                                '</div>';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString,
                maxWidth: 600
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: {{ product.latitude }}, lng: {{ product.longitude }}},
                map: map,
                title: '{{ product.city }}',
                label: '{{ product.address }}'
            });
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        {% endfor %}
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC1c34AXAQ5Y3yV43Alj_ieMRaDPb0qZ44&callback=initMap" async defer>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not setting its content dynamically. To do so you have to create marker from another function

```
  <section class="content jumbotron jumbotron-full-height">
        <div class="item slide-1">
            <div id="home-map"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script>
        var map,infowindow;
        function initMap() {

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('home-map'), {
                center: {lat: 52.1326, lng: 5.2913},
                zoom: 6,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
                styles: [
                    {
                        featureType: 'all',
                        stylers: [
                            { saturation: 0 }
                        ]
                    },{
                        featureType: 'road.arterial',
                        elementType: 'geometry',
                        stylers: [
                            { hue: '#00ffee' },
                            { saturation: 0 }
                        ]
                    },{
                        featureType: 'poi.business',
                        elementType: 'labels',
                        stylers: [
                            { visibility: 'off' }
                        ]
                    },{
                        featureType: 'road',
                        elementType: 'labels',
                        stylers: [
                            { visibility: 'on' }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            });

             infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    maxWidth: 600
                });

            {% for product in products %}
                createMarker(product )
            {% endfor %}
        }

       function createMarker(product){

        var contentString = '<div class="info-window">'+
                                        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div id="window-content">'+
                                            '{% set path = product.image is not null ? product.image.path|imagine_filter(filter|default('sylius_shop_map_thumbnail')) : 'http://placehold.it/200x200' %}'+
                                            '<img src="{{ path }}" />'+
                                            '<h1>{{ product.code }}</h1>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<h2>{{ product.city }} - {{ product.country }}</h2>'+
                                        '<p><strong> Description: </strong>{{  product.shortDescription }}</p>'+
                                        '<p><strong> Price: </strong>from {{ product.price|sylius_price }} a day.</p>'+
                                        '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ path("sylius_shop_product_show", {"slug": product.slug}) }}">more info</a>'+
                                    '</div>';


                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: {{ product.latitude }}, lng: {{ product.longitude }}},
                    map: map,
                    title: '{{ product.city }}',
                    label: '{{ product.address }}'
                });
                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
       }


    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC1c34AXAQ5Y3yV43Alj_ieMRaDPb0qZ44&callback=initMap" async defer>
    </script>
```

Be sure to declare infowindow as a global variable

Comment: its still not working because "product" is undefined in the createMarker function, I need to place a {% for product in products %} somewhere for the function to know which product it is referring to.

Comment: oh that was a typing mistake. i fix that you can try now

Comment: I still get error Variable "product" does not exist in SyliusShopBundle:Homepage:index.html.twig at line 79 -> this is line 79: '{% set path = product.image is not null ? product.image.path|imagine_filter(filter|default('sylius_shop_map_thumbnail')) : 'http://placehold.it/200x200' %}'+

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> and <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> What exactly did you fix in your original typing mistake?

Comment: Do you know why it still isn't working? Its still saying the product is undefined. Thank you.

Comment: can you show me your code through link so i can inspect. Because it always works for me